# Getting an error with a web browser control in a WinForms Application

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I am trying to use a webbrowser control in a winforms app.  In my app, when I try to navigate to places that work fine in IE or Chrome, I get a "Script Error" window stating that "An error has ocurred in the script on this page."  with "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method."  Yet, I can still use IE to get to the page without issue.

What am I missing?

The script error is less important to me than the fact that it is behaving differently in my app than it does in a web browser.  My question is this:

Is it possible to embed a web browser in a .Net application that will behave exactly like a stand-alone web browser?  How?

Comment: It is software that controls a webcam, but I'd like it to work with other pages / scripts, too.

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216301/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-webbrowser-control : 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For posterity: I know this isn't a proper fix, but you can actually open up Internet Explorer -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced then look under Browsing for the options Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer & Other). Deselect those and you will solve the problem.

Another option is like this:

```
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

IE probably has the error messages turned off. There is likely a script error that needs resolved.

Comment: The page doesn't function the same, though, even if I turn off errors in the app's web browser.

Answer (score 0):

If this is anything like the using webbrowser control in WinMo, make sure you call InitHTMLControl. Also, in code I've written (webbrowser in WinMo), I also explicitly post DTM_ENABLESCRIPTING to the control. YMMV, but I HTH.

Comment: It seems different from WinMo: I cannot find anything called InitHTMLControl in Winforms.