# Object doesn't support property or method WebBrowser Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, winforms, internet-explorer-9

I have developed a mobile app (in asp.net) and I am using a WinForms application with the WebBrowser control to demo it.

I my main page I am using a script to hide the address bar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        // Set a timeout...
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Hide the address bar!
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }, 0);
    });
</script>
```

This has worked ok an several machines but this morning on a new machine I encountered an popup when the page loads:

[image]

The machine in question has IE9 installed and I have the `Disable Script Debugging` setting Checked.

What is the best way to tackle this issue. Can I add some condition in the JS to not execute when running in IE?

Comment: It would seem that the IE9 Tools>Options Settings are not used by the WebBrowser control. So even though `Disable Script Debugging` is checked in IE, this setting is not propagated to the control.

I managed to switch this off in the control by using `WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I know that this problem is from 2012 but there is an answer for it.

At the top of the `<head>` document where script is added you need to write

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

WinForms WebBrowser control is using Internet Explorer but you need to force the latest version there. For eg. if you are using jQuery 2+ it requires IE 9+ so you need to use at least version 9 or later.

Comment: I am WinForm browser control and facing same problem. How do I handle from browser control?

Answer (score 2):

Webbrowser control doesn't suppert jquery v2.

Use the jquery 1.9.1.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Webbrowser control is a part of the Internet Explorer itself. And Internet Explorer doesnt support the `window.addEventListener` method. Use `window.attachEvent` method instead.

So the script in your page will read like

```
window.attachEvent("load", function () {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx would suggest that IE9 does support addEventListener. Does the WebBrowser control use IE9 if it is installed?