# Create JavaScript custom event

Tags: javascript, events

I would like to create a custom event in JavaScript.

I have a WPF application with a WebBrowser inside, and a HTML page with JavaScript.

I work with a printer. When the state of the printer changes, it triggers an event in .NET.

Then, I call a JavaScript method `OnPrinterStateChanged(state)` with the `InvokeScript` function of the WebBrowser control.

The problem is that I have to implement the method `OnPrinterStateChanged(state)` in my webpage. I can't change the name of the method or subscribe/unsubscribe to the event...

I would like to move the JavaScript method `OnPrinterStateChanged(state)` in a separate JavaScript file.

What I want :

- Subscribe/Unsubscribe to the event in my HTML page and decide what I want to do when the event is triggered (ex. : "function ChangeState")
- When the .NET event is triggered, it calls the `OnPrinterStateChanged(state)` of my separate .js file, then the JavaScript event is triggered and the function `ChangeState` is called.

I found some solutions but I didn't manage to make it work... What is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: What solutions did you find? Please show your attempt so far

Comment: I found http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/ but like I said, I'm a beginner and I don't know exactly if it could do what I want and where use this code...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
function OnPrinterStateChanged(state) {
    var evt = new CustomEvent('printerstatechanged', { detail: state });

    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}


//Listen to your custom event
window.addEventListener('printerstatechanged', function (e) {
    console.log('printer state changed', e.detail);
});
```

An alternative solution would be to use function composition, but then it would be hard to remove specific listeners.

```
function OnPrinterStateChanged(state) {}

function compose(fn1, fn2) {
    return function () {
        fn1.apply(this, arguments);
        fn2.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

//Add a new listener
OnPrinterStateChanged = compose(OnPrinterStateChanged, function (state) {
    console.log('listener 1');
});

//Add another one
OnPrinterStateChanged = compose(OnPrinterStateChanged, function (state) {
     console.log('listener 2');
});
```

EDIT:

Here's how you can do it with jQuery.

```
function OnPrinterStateChanged(state) {
    var evt = $.Event('printerstatechanged');
    evt.state = state;

    $(window).trigger(evt);
}


//Listen to your custom event
$(window).on('printerstatechanged', function (e) {
    console.log('printer state changed', e.state);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! But I got this error : "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'" Any idea why ? I tride to replace by "AttachEvent" ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216301/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-webbrowser-control ) but I have another script error without details.

Comment: @Gab In which browser?

Comment: It's a WebBrowser from WPF so it's Internet Explorer

Comment: @Gab, well this embedded WebBrowser seems outdated then and proabably doesn't support custom events. I suggest that you use a micro library for custom event supports and use then same strategy. Here's a few http://microjs.com/#events

Comment: Ok thank you, tell with if you know one of these libraries or how to do it with Jquery for example... Otherwise, thank you anyway

Answer (score 14):

I like using this `EventDispatcher` constructor method, which, using a dummy element, isolates the events so they will not be fired on any existing DOM element, nor the `window` or `document`.

> I am using `CustomEvent` and not `createEvent` because it's the newer
> approach. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

I like to wrap each native method with these names:

### `on`, `off`, `trigger`

```js
function eventDispatcher(){
  // Create a dummy DOM element, which is a local variable 
  var dummy = document.createTextNode('')

  // Create custom wrappers with nicer names
  return {
    off(...args){ 
      dummy.removeEventListener(...args) 
      return this
    },
    on(...args){ 
      dummy.addEventListener(...args) 
      return this
    },
    trigger(eventName, data){
      if( !eventName ) return
      
      // if the event should be allowed to bubble, 
      // then "dummy" must be in the DOM
      var e = new CustomEvent(eventName, {detail:data})
      dummy.dispatchEvent(e)
      return this
    }
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////
// initialize the event dispatcher by creating an instance in an isolated way
var myEventDispatcher = eventDispatcher();

////////////////////////////////////
// listen to a "foo" event
myEventDispatcher
  .on('foo', e => console.log(e.type, e.detail) )
  .on('bar', e => console.log(e.type, e.detail) )

////////////////////////////////////
// trigger a "foo" event with some data
myEventDispatcher
  .trigger('foo', 123)
  .trigger('bar', 987);
```

---

The above `eventDispatcher` could be integrated into another code, for example, a Constructor:
*(for example some component)*

```js
function eventDispatcher(){
  var dummy = document.createTextNode('')

  return {
    off(...args){ 
      dummy.removeEventListener(...args) 
      return this
    },
    on(...args){ 
      dummy.addEventListener(...args) 
      return this
    },
    trigger(eventName, data){
      if( !eventName ) return
      var e = new CustomEvent(eventName, {detail:data})
      dummy.dispatchEvent(e)
      return this
    }
  }
}

/////////////////////////////
// Some component: 

var MyComponent = function(){
  // merge `EventDispatcher` instance into "this" instance
  Object.assign(this, eventDispatcher())
  
  // set some default value
  this.value = 1
}

MyComponent.prototype = {
  set value(v){
    this.trigger('change', v)
  }
}

var comp = new MyComponent();

// bind a listener to "comp" (which itself is an instance of "MyComponent")
comp.on('change', e => console.log("Type:", e.type,", Value:", e.detail) )

// set some value
comp.value = 3;
```

---

**See my related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432013/104380), which shows a more complex implementation of the above**

Comment: Will not using `on` and `trigger` create an incompatibility with jQuery?

Comment: No, since these methods are declared on the `EventDispatcher` Object, which isn't a jQuery object.. it will only conflict if you extend any jQuery object with an instance of `EventDispatcher`, which no person would ever do because it makes no sense.

Comment: Works perfectly, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a solution.

I had to change the WebBrowser IE Version to Internet Explorer 11: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

And  then :

```
function OnPrinterStateChanged(state) {

    var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
    evt.state = state;
    evt.initEvent("printerstatechanged", true, false);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);

}


window.addEventListener('printerstatechanged', function (e) {
  // Do something
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `document.createEvent` has been replaced by the `CustomEvent` or `Event` constructors and you should use that instead. I am pretty sure IE 11 supports them.

Comment: IE doesn't support either. You have to use the "old fashioned way" to acquire IE support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: IE11 does support `CustomEvent` @Derick

Comment: Mozilla has a [simple polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill) for browsers that don't support `CustomEvent` (basically just IE)

Answer (score 2):

Requirement: ES6

```js
let MyClass = (function () {
    let __sym = Symbol('MyClass');

    class MyClass {
        constructor() {
            this[__sym] = {};
        }
        on(event, callback) {
            this[__sym][event] = { callback: callback }
        }
        getError() {
            let event = this[__sym].error;

            if (event && event.callback) {
                event.callback('some parameter');
            }
        }
    }

    return MyClass;
}());

let myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('error:', e);
});

console.log('before getting error:');

myClass.getError();
```