# Trigger CustomEvent in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to create custom event in vanilla javascript, but don't really understand how to trigger it. As far as I know there is `jQuery` method `trigger('customEvent')`, but how is it made in `Vanilla JS`? Can't find any info regarding that.

Creating `CustomEvent`:

```
var addColor = function (elem) {

    elem.classList.add('red');
    var event = new CustomEvent('madeRed');
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Attaching `addEventListener` to the element

```
var elem = document.querySelector('div');
addColor(elem);

elem.addEventListener('madeRed', function (elem) {
    elem.classList.add('color-do-changed');
}, false);
```

Comment: So what is your actual problem? BTW, you are dispatching the event before adding the event listener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create JavaScript custom event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344625/create-javascript-custom-event)

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine, you just decided to listen to the event *after* calling it. Also if you want to pass custom data then pass it through [detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/detail). You didn't pass anything but were expecting the event parameter to be your element.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('div');

var addColor = function (elem) {
    elem.classList.add('red');
    var event = new CustomEvent('madeRed', {
      detail: {
        elem
      }
    });
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
};

elem.addEventListener('madeRed', function (event) {
    event.detail.elem.classList.add('color-do-changed');
}, false);


addColor(elem);
```

```css
.red { color: red }
.color-do-changed { text-decoration: underline }
```

```html
<div>Make me red</div>
```

Comment: so to trigger it I have to simply call elem.dispatchEvent(event); ?

Comment: @DavidC.Yes, you only need the second argument if you want to pass some custom data through