# Click href button/link using C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, html, web, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to click a href link from a website which will lead me to another page of the website this is my code:

```
private const string baseURL = "https://abv.bg/";

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    localWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
    localWebBrowser.Navigate(baseURL);
}

private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(localWebBrowser.Url.ToString());
    HtmlElement lostPasswordButton = ObtainHtmlElementById(localWebBrowser, "lostPasswordLink");
    if (lostPasswordButton == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Couldn't find {nameof(lostPasswordButton)}");
    }
    lostPasswordButton.InvokeMember("click");
}

private HtmlElement ObtainHtmlElementById(WebBrowser webBrowser, string elementName)
{
    return webBrowser.Document.GetElementById(elementName);
}
```

This is the html of the button:

[image]

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216301/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-webbrowser-control

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/

Comment: By default the web browser control works in IE7 mode which is before IE supported AddeventListener. To get it to work, you need to force it to a higher rendering mode either via meta tag or via registry entry. The links above explain how.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the respone @AlexanderRyanBaggett