# c# webbrowser not supported @{ Layout = null; }

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

i have error about script error that stopped cshtml.

line : 2
error code : 0
error : object doesn't support this property or method

here's my code

## winform

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost:8080?name=david");
}
```

## cshtml

in error line

```
@{  <-- line 2
    Layout = null;  
}
<html>
<head>
<script src="../../Resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
...
```

how can i fix error? hopely want to fix only in winform code. cuz cshtml file is not mine.(cant fix)

Comment: Layout = null;` is the ` at the end needed?

Comment: sry.. my mistake i modified

Comment: Seems this is IE related problem, since `WebBrowser` control uses IE by default. Try using `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true` & disable script debugging in IE.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379150/6448640

Comment: I already tyied using ScriptErrosSuppressed. but it doesn't work. it just hide script error. this cshtml contain only javascript. i hope to continue if got error

Comment: I would recommend you to try some other webbrowser, something like https://github.com/hmsintrepide/GeckoFX-Browser

Comment: Hi VDN, i tried you told that GeckoFX Browser. it worked but this additional has about almost 35M. i just consider to use this..